# How to avoid back to login menu or homepage after refresh page in dashboard

Tags: reactjs

i build my website and creat all component like homepage, dashboard, login, etc. and when i login to dashboard and create other menu after i save, the page back to login screen or homepage again, after i create a newcode it always back to homepage or login screen again, how to avoid?

parent class include reducer

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Router, Switch} from 'react-router';
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';

import LandingLayout from './layouts/LandingLayout.js';
import App from './containers/App'
import reducer from './reducers'
import Login from './containers/Login'
import Browse from './containers/Browse'
import Home from './containers/Home'
import About from './containers/About'
import Contact from './containers/Contact'
import Input from './containers/Input'
import Detail from './containers/Detail'

const store = createStore(reducer);
const customHistory = createHashHistory();

render(
  <Provider store = {store}>
      <Router history={customHistory}>
          <div>
              <Switch>
                  <Route exact path='/' render={() => <LandingLayout><App /></LandingLayout>}/>
                  <Route exact path='/Home' render={() => <LandingLayout><Home /></LandingLayout>}/>
                  <Route exact path='/Input' render={() => <LandingLayout><Input /></LandingLayout>}/>
                  <Route exact path='/Detail' render={() => <LandingLayout><Detail /></LandingLayout>}/>
                  <Route exact path='/About' render={() => <LandingLayout><About /></LandingLayout>}/>
                  <Route exact path='/Contact' render={() => <LandingLayout><Contact /></LandingLayout>}/>
                  <Route exact path='/login' render={() => <LandingLayout><Login /></LandingLayout>}/>
                  <Route exact path='/browse' render={() => <LandingLayout><Browse /></LandingLayout>} />
              </Switch>
          </div>
      </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for this case:

1) After login use target="_blank" to open a new tab that cannot back to prev page :)

2) Use history package: `history.replace('/dashboard')`